# How to change color of a text if it comes after a certain text?

Tags: javascript, text, colors

How can i change color of a text if it comes after a certain text ? and only the word that comes after and leave the rest by there default color
eg : any word comes after Die to be red , das to be green , der to be blue

der mann (blue)
die frau (red)
das buch (green)

die frau ist Schön . (the only part to become red is *die frau* leaving *ist Schön* black .

Appreciate your help

i don't know how to write codes

Answer (score 0):

Split the text and colorize the word after any of the "key" words.

```js
var dict = {
  der: 'blue',
  die: 'red',
  das: 'green'
}

var text = "der mann die frau das buch"

output = document.querySelector(".output");

output.innerHTML = colorize(text, dict);

function colorize(text, dict) {
  var next = null;
  return text.split(" ").map(function(word) {
    if (next) {
      word = `<font color="${next}">${word}</font>`;
      next = null;
    } else {
      next = dict[word]
    }
    return word;
  }).join(" ");

}
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to create a dictionary (`Map`) of key-words and their associated colors. You can build a regular expression to locate words that follow a key-word, and wrap them in a span to add color. If you use a positive look-behind, you can match on the key-word.

```js
const wordColorMap = new Map(Object.entries({
  'das': '#00FF00',
  'der': '#0000FF',
  'die': '#FF0000',
}));

const highlightNextWords = (el, dictionary) => {
  let updatedHtml = el.innerText; // Just grab the plain text
  for (let [word, color] of dictionary) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`(?<=${word}\\s+)(\\S+)`, 'ig');
    updatedHtml = updatedHtml.replaceAll(pattern, (nextWord) => {
      const color = wordColorMap.get(word.toLowerCase());
      return `<span style="color:${color}">${nextWord}</span>`;
    });
  }
  el.innerHTML = updatedHtml; // Set HTML text
};

highlightNextWords(document.querySelector('span'), wordColorMap);
```

```html
<span>
der mann die frau das buch
der mann die frau das buch
der mann die frau das buch
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `span` tag.

Example:

```html
<p> Hello <span style="color: green;"> John </span> </p>
```